# Recover Postman Scratchpad data after deprecate?

Tags: postman

Got a user who doesn't use Postman often, and so missed the messages about migrating from Scratchpad.  It's well past the 9/15 deadline, but is there somewhere the Scratchpad data is stored so they can recover their work?

Answer (score 1):

From the Lightweight API Client, you can Export the Scratch Pad data from the app using the `⚙️ > Settings > Data > Export` menu option.